# How Are Multiple Forms Handled?

Tags: html, forms

I have a webpage, which has an overall form element surrounding all the code on the page between the `<body> ... </body>` tags on the page.

As part of the webpage, there are two additional forms inside this to add and edit rows on a tables contained on the webpage.

How are the form elements handled on a webpage?  Will the browser know what to process a webpage laid out:

```
<body>
<form id="FullPageForm">
Content here.
    <form id="AdditionalFomr1">
        Form1 elements only
    </form>
    <form id="AdditionalFomr2">
        Form2 elements only
    </form>
</form>
</body>
```

Can the browser isolate the various different form sections on the page correctly?

Comment: Having forms inside other forms **isn't valid**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `<forms>` nested inside other `<forms>` is not valid in HTML4 or HTML5.

See the relevant part of the [**HTML5 Specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) below:

> **4.10.3** The `<form>` element - Content model: Flow content, but with no `<form>` element descendants.

They can however, be siblings, e.g.

```
<form id="AdditionalFomr1">
    Form1 elements only
</form>
<form id="AdditionalFomr2">
    Form2 elements only
</form>
<form id="AdditionalFomr3">
    Form3 elements only
</form>
```

Now that your forms are separated, it's easy to differentiate between what action should happen when each one is submitted etc.

Comment: Thanks man.  Honestly did not know that nested form elements were not allowed.  I'm off now to spend a few hours tweaking my code!!

Answer (score 1):

it will not work. nested variables is not supported by any browser.

Answer (score 0):

ya your code is working
but you have done silly mistake in above code
**see in  tag you used '?' instead of '>' sign**
and put forms in a table form
so you can get formal look